# How to return the only value that is not repeated in this Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question in Javascript.

This is the following Array: `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

I would like to return the only value that does not repeat, that is, 1.

Any suggestions?

I have this:

```
var result = arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) !== 0);
```

Comment: Anything you've tried so far ?

Comment: show us the things you have tried so far.

Comment: @Esko that's not the same

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`

You can compare `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` and `filter()`

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let res = arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));

console.log(res)
```

If you only want the first element you can use `find()`

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let res = arr.find(x => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));

console.log(res)
```

You can remove duplicates using `Set()` and then use `filter()` on it.

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let res = [...new Set(arr)].filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));

console.log(res)
```

#### Using nested `filter()`

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let res = arr.filter(x => arr.filter(a => a === x).length === 1);
console.log(res)
```

#### Using Object and `reduce()`

This one is best regarding time complexity.

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let obj = arr.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1,ac),{});
let res = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => obj[x] === 1).map(x => +x || x);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Never thought if this solution before, neat one.

Comment: And, in the second approach, you can use `let res = arr.find((x,i) => i === arr.lastIndexOf(x));` instead.

Comment: Explanation of how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297644/can-anyone-explain-the-following-javascript-code-for-unique-value-how-is-it-inte/52297778#52297778

Comment: Oh, perfect! Thank you.